# How to create a cross platform duplex web service communication

Tags: web-services, websocket, nat, duplex, wcf-interoperability

I would like to create a web service in .Net that clients of different types (Web, exe, java) can consume despite of the language they are written with.

In addition, it needs to support callbacks and be able to easily pass through firewalls and NATs (knowing a client internal IP might change, or be removed from NAT).

Thirdly, since it is an enterprise product, I want to avoid being dependent on 3rd parties, especially ones that demand a certain environment or that customer will not want.

What kind of technologies or approaches can I use?

I am looking at web sockets, but there also I see a lot of complexities and I am not sure there aren't a lot of topology and interoperability border cases that may make me unreliable.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For simple request-response services, you can use REST (over HTTP).  Any client technology can access HTTP at this point (even CLI) and REST is a well-known and well-understood distributed mechanism.  The issue involves the callbacks.  There are frameworks that handle HTTP callbacks (simple google search will give you good answers), but imo, the solutions that I have seen are clumsy.

Unlike normal HTTP, WebSocket is a persistent connection.  And like any other IETF and W3C specification (or any other standard for that matter), there are various implementations with various degrees of reliability, performance, etc.   There are probably about 100 implementations of WebSocket clients and servers.  Some implementations handle real-world issues like reconnections, network intermediaries, high scalability, mobile capabilities, etc... and some implementations just do not.  I would suggest you pick an implementation that provides these enterprise-grade features.

Btw, WebSocket is pretty darn simple